# Adding some text on a page break

Tags: page-breaking, conditionals, longtable

How can one test if certain chunks of text (say, numbered questions in a questionnaire) is split between two pages and add automatically related text ("Continued question NN") on the top of the second page?

(That is what longtable does with its head, but I need it for plain text.)

I doubt if MWE make sense here, 'cause I'm not reporting a bug and I cannot suggest any solution to the problem. Anyway, let it be.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{lines=9,showframe}

\def\lorem{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
  sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
  aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco
  laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
  dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu
  fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non
  proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est
  laborum.}

\newcounter{question}
\newcommand\question[1]{\par
\refstepcounter{question}\textbf{\thequestion.} #1\par}

\begin{document}
\question{\lorem}
\question{\lorem}
\question{\lorem}

\end{document}
```

I would like to have a line *Continued question 2* as a 1st line of page 2 **body** for 9-lines body and nothing for 10-lines body. As `longtable` does with its `...\endhead` instruction.

---

I think about 2 solutions: one just puts the chunk in a `vbox`, tests if its height is greater than the remaining space and, if necessary, `vsplits` it and adds page break followed by the desired text and the remainigs (iterating if it is too big for one page).

Another one puts 2 labels at the beginning and the end of a chunk and defines a command for page N (the command name includes N as its part) that prints the desired line if these two label appears on pages N-1 and N. This command can be called from `\output`, but I don't know the right way and moment to do it.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: I added MWE in my question although I doubt if it makes sense here

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure in your specific case as you didn't paste a WME, but I would have a serious look to the extramarks package.
The doc is here : http://www.ntg.nl/maps/16/29.pdf (p.13) and you'll find a sample just like this one :

```
\usepackage{extramarks}
...
\pagestyle{fancy}
\lhead{\firstxmark}
\rfoot{\lastxmark}
...
\extramarks{}{Continued on next page\ldots}
    Some text that may or may not cross a page boundary...
\extramarks{Continued\ldots}{}
```

Comment: I'd like to have this line in the page body, not in the header (which is already used; also a figure may occure between the head and the body).